Is there an option to enable custom error details in the Sitecore Experience Editor (XM Cloud)?
Is there an option to enable custom error details in the Sitecore Experience Editor (XM Cloud)? Typically, this involves adjusting settings in the web.config file. Additionally, can modifications be made to the web.config in an XM Cloud instance?
I can see a couple of unexpected errors.


You can easily see the CM log files in the Deploy app.

To enable custom error details in the Sitecore XM Cloud, you can utilize XDT transformation for the web.config file. In XM Cloud, XDT transforms are supported by specifying the fully qualified paths to XDT source files and configuration destination files in the xmcloud.build.json file. These paths should be relative to the web root of the built code.
Here's an example configuration for xmcloud.build.json:
{
  "renderingHosts": {
    "xmcloudpreview": {
      "path": "./src/sxastarter",
      "nodeVersion": "20.10.0",
      "jssDeploymentSecret": "<secret>",
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "sxa",
      "lintCommand": "lint",
      "startCommand": "start:production",
      "buildCommand": "build",
      "runCommand": "next:start"
    }
  },
  "transforms": [
    {
      "xdtPath": "/app_data/xdts/web.config.xdt",
      "targetPath": "/web.config"
    }
  ],
  "postActions": {
    "actions": {
      "warmUpCm": {
        "urls": [
          "/sitecore/shell",
          "/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx?sc_bw=1",
          "/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad"
        ]
      },
      "populateSchema": {
        "indexNames": []
      },
      "reindex": {
        "indexNames": []
      }
    }
  }
}


In your XM Cloud repository, under XmCloudSXAStarter platform project, create an App_Data -> Xdts folder and place your Web.config.xdt file there. (As we defined in xmcloud.build.json file). The contents of this file would be similar to:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="sitecore">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>



This configuration will turn off custom error mode specifically for the 'Sitecore' path in the web.config file.
For more details on defining XDT files and XM Cloud build configuration, you can refer to the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/the-xm-cloud-build-configuration.html
You can consult the PLAY! Summit project repository for a working example of the xmcloud.build.json file.

Hi Raman,
You are referring to the incorrect file. In the XDT file, it should be a transformation file, not the exact web.config file attributes. Can you please review and correct this information?
Thanks.

To assist others facing similar issues with XM Cloud XDT (XML Document Transform) files, I am sharing the steps I took to resolve the problem.
Configuration 1 - Initial XDT File (Incorrect Format)
The following XDT configuration did not work because it was not in the correct XDT format:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location path="sitecore">
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>

Configuration 2 - Attempted XDT File (Incorrect)
The following attempt also failed:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(mode)" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Sitecore Support Feedback
I raised a support ticket with the Sitecore team. Their feedback was:
Hi Jitendra,
Thank you for contacting Sitecore Support. I was able to reproduce the issue using the Match attribute for xdt:Locator on the  element:
<customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(mode)" />

However, using a different attribute, such as Condition, successfully replaced the  element. For example:
<customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Condition(@mode!='Off')"/>

This behavior is unexpected, and we are reviewing it further. In the meantime, please use the Condition attribute on the  element."
Final Resolution
Based on Sitecore’s advice, I used a conditional match off Condition(@mode!='Off') , which resolved the issue. Here is the correct XDT configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Condition(@mode!='Off')"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

This solution ensures the  mode is set to "Off" using an explicit condition. I hope this information is helpful to others encountering similar issues.
